# How to use std::bind with std::function and std::map

Tags: c++11, function-pointers

I am trying to create a map of std::function and then trying to bind it few parameters, but it is giving an error.
So, my std::function definition is

```
using abc = std::function<double(const double& t1, const double& t2)>;
```

and the map is

```
std::map<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, abc> conversion_;
```

The way I am trying to insert in this map is

```
conversion_.emplace(
            std::make_pair("a", "b"),
            std::bind(conversion, 3, std::placeholders::_1));

conversion_.find(std::make_pair("a", "b"))->second(4); -- Access
```

I have defined the function conversion, but when I am trying to access the function it is giving the below error

```
 error: no match for call to ‘(const std::function<double(const double&, const double&)>) (int)’
```

Adding full code:
conversion function is defined in a separate file :

```
namespace x
{
    double conversion(const double& a, const double& b);
}
```

Header file where I am trying to define map

```
namespace x
{
    class main 
    {
    public:
        using abc = std::function<double(const double& t1, const double& t2)>;
        main();
    private:
        std::map<std::pair<std::string, std::string>, abc> conversion_;
    };
}
```

The CPP file

```
namespace x
{
main::main() 
{
    conversion_.emplace(
        std::make_pair("a", "b"),
        std::bind(conversion, 3, std::placeholders::_1));
    auto m = conversion_.find(std::make_pair("a", "b"))->second(4);
}
}
```

Comment: It looks like the `bind` is not generating compatible object. What is the declaration of `conversion`?

Comment: Post **all** the code. You can't just omit a key detail like that, thinking it just _must_ be correct.

Comment: Post a [mcve]. Right now, we don't know what `conversion` is, for example. But even without it: your `abc` is a function of two parameters, but you're calling it with only one. Look into that.

Comment: Are you allowed to use a lambda in place of `bind`?

Comment: Yes. I can use lamda, but how will that make it easier?

Comment: @AnkitAgarwal: Lambdas are quite a bit readable and easier to use than `std::bind` because they basically look like functions. @phyxnj has the answer you need, but you could replace your bind with a lambda, and only accept a single arg.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess `conversion` is function as `double(const double& t1, const double& t2)`. If so, `std::bind(conversion, 3, std::placeholders::_1)` define a functor which requires one argument a `double` (the other argument of `conversion` is fixed as `3`) and return `double`. You just need modify `abc` into `std::function<double(const double& t1)>;`